# Windows UWP Richtexteditor

Tags: windows, uwp

I have a html string like "

> *From: User Demo* 
>   ABC TEST

". I need to display this string in a uwp xaml control which will render this in html format.
Sample Attached. Im new to Windows App development.

Suggest me some control with sample code which will fulfill my requirement.

PS: This content is dynamic and might contain any basic html tags.

Comment: My html string is <div><br /> </div> <blockquote><em>From: Secretary SAMPLE</em><br /> <div style="border: 1px dashed #CCCCCC;"> <div>What do you think we can do to celebrate the year-end</div> </div> </blockquote>.  A string with html tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, you can use `WebView` element with `NavigateToString`method.
Look this [sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-WebView-control-sample-58ad63f7) for Windows 8.1 App which you can use in UWP.

At second, install [Windows App Studio WinRT XAML & UWP Libraries](https://github.com/wasteam/waslibs) and use `HtmlBlock` control which convert HTML string into native UWP controls

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Andrii. I am able to render html tags through Webview. Now one another problem is, I need to have this Webview as one of the control inside Gridview datatemplate. How would i bind the list of data to this Webview inside Gridview.

Comment: If it's not related to this topic - please create a new question

Comment: Created a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41568989/access-webview-inside-gridview-datatemplate