# Access Webview inside Gridview datatemplate

Tags: gridview, webview, uwp

I have Webview as one of the control inside Gridview datatemplate. How would i access and bind data to this Webview inside Gridview.

I have tried VisualTreeHelper.GetChildren method. But could not succeed. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to resolve with same VisualTreeHelper.GetChildren method. Previously i was parsing child controls as Control type. Since WebView is a Framework element I did not get WebView control. Now when I try to parse as FramewoekElement, I am able to get it. Still wondering if there would be any better solution??